# Maximum number of vertices in a 5-regular planar graph

Tags: graph-theory

I know how to find the minimum number of vertices in such a graph, as shown below:

Given a planar graph $G$ of order $n$ and size $m$, $n$ and $m$ must satisfy:

$$
m\le 3n-6.
$$

Since $\delta(G)=5$, we know $m\ge\displaystyle{\frac{5n}{2}}$. Thus

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5n}{2}\le m&\le 3n-6\\
5n&\le 6n-12\\
-n&\le -12\\
n&\ge 12
\end{align}
$$

However, how do we find the MAXIMUM number of vertices? I understand it would use a similar method, but I can't figure it out for some reason.

Comment: Without additional conditions (e.g., connectedness), you can just take several disjoint copies of the icosahedron graph

Comment: But how does that show the maximum number of vertices?

Comment: Maximum does not exist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim.** There is no upper bound on the size of a connected planar 5-regular graph.

*Proof.*

[image]
$\square$

Comment: That's a beautiful graph and proof that you can have a planar 5-regular graph with (counts) 32 vertices.  Can it be transformed into a larger such graph?  If this was built from a smaller planar 5-regular graph, I can't see it off the top of my head.

Comment: Take a larger copy of the graph, with the same orientation, and place it so that the inner circle of one coincides with the outer circle of the other. Repeat...

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: How does placing the circle within another result in a 5-regular graph? The degree of each point on the circle will be 8 with the circle intact, and 6 with the circle removed.